# Python regex to replace C function or typedef body

Tags: c, regex, function, python-3.x, typedef

what regex could remove whole function body even, if curly brackets are nested ? 
What I have so far is `re.sub('{.*?}', '', source)` however, it doesn't work with nested brackets so it wont remove line 5 and 6. I know that similiar question to this is already written here several times, however, still cannot find solution

```
1. int foo(void){
2.    if(cond){
3.        code
4.    }
5.    next few
6.    lines of code
7. }
10. typedef struct strfoo{
11.    code
12. }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: In this case you'd want to use a *stack* to know when you got back to the outer-most level of braces. To do this you'd want to push open braces onto the stack, and pop them off when you see a closing brace. Problems that are stack-based in nature are not good candidates for regex.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns.

Comment: Thanks for replies guys, it looks like that i will have to do that via finite state automat, wanted to avoid that, but...
Thanks anyway :)